# Remove characters in a string that matches a certain pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to know if there is some regular expression or something I could use that would remove instances where I have 3 letters followed by a number in a string?

For example, I have this corpus

```
c = [CLE2 - Single Smalls station 117,
HOU2 - mathdenn,
[SAT2] Pack Singles > Line 7 > Station 04 Kiosk Ticket - ZT410 Shipping Label Not Printing Correcly,
[HOU2] Multiple GW Stations Down in AFE2]
```

I would want to apply some function that will then return

```
c = [Single Smalls station 117
 - mathdenn,
 Pack Singles > Line 7 > Station 04 Kiosk Ticket - ZT410 Shipping Label Not Printing Correcly
 Multiple GW Stations Down in ]
```

Looking for neat pythonic ways of achieving this. I read through regular expressions online a little but I have not found a way to specify I want to remove instances where we have 3 characters followed by a number, so I wouldn't say this answers my question.

I tried doing something like this:

```
regex = re.compile('[a-z][0-9]')
regex.findall(corpus[0])
```

But this just returns instances where we have a char followed by a number. Perhaps some type of modification of this?

Comment: Apparently you don't know where to start with your regex. Please check out [Reference - What does this regex mean resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618), and [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) for more info on regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pythonic way:

```
import re

c = '''[CLE2 - Single Smalls station 117,
HOU2 - mathdenn,
[SAT2] Pack Singles > Line 7 > Station 04 Kiosk Ticket - ZT410 Shipping Label Not Printing Correcly,
[HOU2] Multiple GW Stations Down in AFE2]'''

for substr in re.findall(r'\W([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d)\W', c):
    c = c.replace(substr, '')
c = c.replace('[]', '')
print(c)
```

Comment: Could this also be extended so that we can remove any string instances that have a character followed by a number? ZT410 needs to be removed as well.

Comment: for substr in re.findall(r'\W([A-Z][A-Z]\d{3})\W', c):
    c = c.replace(substr, '')